# How do I get Emacs to interpret M-left as previous word?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, key-binding, iterm2

I'm very used to having Emacs interpret `M-left/M-right` as backword/forwards word. However, last night, for some reason, Emacs started interpreting `M-left` as `D` and `M-right` as `C`.

I'm wondering how I can restore the default behavior. I haven't changed my .emacs file at all, and I'm using iTerm, with the option key set as meta.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

--Edit--

I've figured out that the problem is with iTerm and not Emacs. Emacs interprets the commands correctly in the built-in terminal, but not in emacs.

Comment: ", but not in **iTerm**"?